# How can I calculate the gradient of the product of a matrix and a vector?

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

Suppose $$ W \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, \quad h \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $$
What is $\nabla_WWh$ ?

In other words, how to calculate the gradient of $ \ Wh \ $ with respect to $ \ W \ $ ?

Comment: Intuitively, the answer of my question should be $h$ just like what you said. But in the book Deep Learning, the answer is $h^T$. Do you know why? (See Algorithm 6.4, page 209, http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html)

Comment: I simplified the equation for convenience.  The original equation(in the pseudo codes of Algorithm 6.4) in the book is: $ \nabla_{W^{(k)}}J = gh^{(k-1)T}+\lambda\nabla_{W^{(k)}}{\Omega(\theta)}$. Please note the superscript $T$

Comment: Hi, Rahul. Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward option is to utilize the $\textrm{vec}$ [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products)
\begin{align}
\textrm{vec}\left(AXB\right) = \left(B^T \otimes A\right) \textrm{vec}\left(X\right).
\end{align}

So,
\begin{align}
\textrm{vec}\left(Wh\right) 
&= \textrm{vec}\left(IWh\right) \\
&= \left(h^T \otimes I\right) \textrm{vec}\left(W\right).
\end{align}

Then, take the derivative with respect to $W$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \textrm{vec}\left(W\right)} \left\{\left(h^T \otimes I\right) \textrm{vec}\left(W\right) \right\}
&= h^T \otimes I  \ ,
\end{align}
where $I$ is an Identity matrix of appropriate size.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that's a professional one! Another question: do I need to unvec the result and how?

Comment: no, you don't need to unvec (the result is already in a matrix form).

Comment: But is the Hadamard product of $h^T \otimes I$ defined?

Comment: $\otimes$ is a Kronecker product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: Oh, I see. But is $ \ \nabla_WWh \ $ the same as $ \ \nabla_{vec(W)} {vec(Wh)} \ $ ?

Comment: Yes, see, e.g., page 4 of http://www4.ncsu.edu/~pfackler/MatCalc.pdf

Comment: OK, I got it. Actually, I am trying to get rid of $ \  \otimes I \ $, because the result will be used in another place. Is $ \ h^T \otimes I \ $ equivalent to $ \ h^T \ $? And how to prove it?

Comment: if you want to avoid Kronecker products then i think you have to consider Rahul's comments.

Comment: Well, it's hard to explain here because we are not talking face to face. But still thanks a lot for your answers and patience.

Comment: Hi, I have raised a new question to explain this problem in detail. Hope you are still interested in it and give a professional answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970202/a-matrix-calculus-problem-in-backpropagation-encountered-when-studying-deep-lear