# Matrix calculus for RNN equations

Tags: matrix-calculus, machine-learning

In the [deep learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html) we have the standard RNN with 
[these equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4warZ.png). It calculates various derivatives, [including one for W](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izqRx.png).

I understand that:

- $1 - {(h^{(t)})}^2 $ is coming from the derivative of $tanh$
- $h^{(t-1)}$ is coming from the chain rule

What I don't understand:

- where is the $diag$ coming from?
- where is the transpose for $h^{(t-1)}$ is coming from?
- why are they on the particular order they are in (apart from that this way the dimensions match). It feels like the gradient of L just got somehow between the parts of the derivate of $h^{(t)}$

Thank you

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970202/a-matrix-calculus-problem-in-backpropagation-encountered-when-studying-deep-lear/2974250#2974250