# How to apply chain rule on matrix

Tags: inner-products, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

### Gradient of $\frac{dL}{dX}$ using chain rule

With the chain rule, $\frac{dL}{dX} = \frac{dY}{dX} \cdot \frac{dL}{dY}$, and $\frac{dY}{dX} = W$ for the product `Y = X•W`.

### Q1

I suppose I need to make $\frac{dY}{dX}$ into  a transpose $W^\intercal$ to match the shape. For instance, if `X` shape is `(, 3)` as per numpy, the last axis of shape($\frac{dY}{dX}$) needs to be `3` (so that $\frac{dY}{dX} \cdot dX^\intercal \rightarrow dY$ : `(m,3) • (3,n) → (m, n)`?)

However, not sure if this is correct and why, hence appreciate any explanations.

### Q2

How can I apply the chain rule formula to matrix?

$\frac{dL}{dX} = W^\intercal \cdot \frac{dL}{dY}$

This cannot be calculated because of the shape mismatch where $W^\intercal$ is `(4, 3)` and $\frac{dL}{dY}$ is `(, 4)`.

Likewise with $\frac{dL}{dW} = X^\intercal \cdot \frac{dL}{dY}$ because $X^\intercal$ is `(,3)` and $\frac{dL}{dY}$ is `(, 4)`.

What thinking, rational or transformation can I apply to get over this?

> There are typos in the diagram. `(,4)` is `(4,)` etc. In my
> brain, 1D array of 4 element was `(,4)` but in NumPy, it is
> `(4,)`.

[image]

---

#### For $\frac{dL}{dX}$

I saw the answer is swapping the positions, but no idea where it came from and why.

$\frac{dL}{dX} = \frac{dL}{dY} \cdot W^\intercal$

Instead of:

$\frac{dL}{dX} = W^\intercal \cdot \frac{dL}{dY}$

#### For $\frac{dL}{dW}$

The shape of $X^\intercal$ `(,3)` and $\frac{dL}{dY}$ `(, 4)` need to be transformed into `(3, 1)` and `(1, 4)` to match the shapes, but no idea where it came from and why.

[image]

## Geometry

In my understanding, `X•W` is extracting the $\vec{\mathbf{W}}$ dimension part of `X` by truncating the other dimensions of `X` geometrically. If so,  $\frac{dL}{dX}$ and $\frac{dL}{dW}$ are  restoring the truncated dimensions? Not sure this is correct but if so, would it be possible to visualize it like `X•W` projection in the diagram?

[image]

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you would like to find the gradient of $L = A \cdot B \equiv \operatorname{Trace}(X^T W)$ with respect to $W$, right? If yes, then my personal opinion stay away from chain rule. Better consider differentials and then compute your desired gradient. So, $dL = \operatorname{Trace}(X^T dW) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial L}{\partial W} = X$ (or it can be $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W^T} = X^T$ depending on the choice of layout)

Comment: @user550103, thanks for the follow up. The reason chain-rule is there is because it is essential part of the neural-network (NN) back propagation. NN cascades multiple layers each contains dot, sigmoid/tanh, softmax, exp, log, etc, hence need to apply chain rule to back-track this cascade chain to get the gradients backwards through layers.

Comment: If you need to calculate the weights for NN without using chain rule, then see here for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970202/a-matrix-calculus-problem-in-backpropagation-encountered-when-studying-deep-lear

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Reti43](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243104/reti43) for pointing to the reference. The detail math is provided by the cs231 Justin Jonson (now in Michigan University) as http://cs231n.stanford.edu/handouts/linear-backprop.pdf which is also available as [Backpropagation for a Linear Layer](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ejustincj/teaching/eecs442/notes/linear-backprop.html).

[cs231n lecture 4](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2019/cs231n_2019_lecture04.pdf) explains the idea.

[image]

The math calculation from step (5) to (6) seems to be a leap, because dot product would not be resulted from two 2D matrices, and `numpy.dot` would produce matrix multiplication as `np.matmul`, hence it would not be a dot product.

The answer in [numpy function to use for mathematical dot product to produce scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65671687/4281353) addressed a way.

[image]

---

### Format of the Weight vector W

Need to note on the weights representation of `W` by Justin Johnson.

In Coursera ML course, Andrew Ng uses a row vector to capture weights of a node. When the number of features in input to a layer is `n`, the row vector size is `n`.

Justin Johnson uses a row vector to represent a layer size, the number of nodes in a layer. Hence if there are `m` nodes in a layer, the row vector size is `m`.

Hence the weight matrix for Andrew Ng is `m x n` meaning m rows of weight vectors, each of which are weights for `n` features for a specific node.

The weight matrix for Justin Johnson is `n x m` meaning n rows of weight vectors, each of which are weights for `m` nodes in a layer, per feature.

[image]

I suppose Justin Johnson regards `layer is a function` whereas Andrew Ng regards `node is a function`.

As I studied Andrew Ng's ML course first, I am using `weight vector per node` approach which results in `W as m x n matrix`. My confusion came from applying `W = m x n` to Justin Jhonson's paper.

---

## Understanding

My understanding by reading through the Justin Johnson's paper is below.

#### Dimension analysis

First frame the dimensions/shapes of the gradients.

[image]

### Derive the gradient

Using the simple one input record `X shape(d,)`, derive the `dL/dX` and extend it to two dimensional input `X shape(n, d)` resulting in `dL/dY @ W`. This is different from  `dL/dy @ W.T` in the Justin Johnson's paper, because of the difference of the weight matrix W representation.

[image]

If something incorrect, very much appreciate any feedbacks.